# Disable distributionManagement in Maven POM

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, liferay, maven-deploy-plugin

I am trying to run a `mvn deploy` goal with maven on my Liferay portlet but am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.
2:deploy (default-deploy) on project MyPortlet: Deployment failed: repository eleme
nt was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -Dal
tDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on pro
ject RiskID: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM
inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout
```

I understand this error will return if you don't include the `<distributionManagement />` tag in the pom.xml, however I don't wish to package this to a remote location and would like to instead deploy to my local tomcat instance; can this be configured?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is not about `dependencyManagement` but rather `distributionManagement`

> Deployment failed: repository eleme
>   nt was not specified in the POM inside `distributionManagement` element or in `-DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url` parameter

The alternative (if you don't want to place it in your `pom.xml` file) is also provided by using the [`altDeploymentRepository`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository) option:

> Specifies an alternative repository to which the project artifacts should be deployed ( other than those specified in `<distributionManagement>` ). 
>   Format: `id::layout::url`

The first element, the `id`, must have a matching with a `server` defined in your `settings.xml` file (where you specify the credentials to use for the specific server).

The layour and the url are then specific to the target repository.

You can then invoke the command as:

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=test:Maven2:http://somewhere:someport
```

Where `test` is the id of a [server](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) element in your [Maven settings](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>test</id>
      <username>my_login</username>
      <password>my_password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

---

**Update**
Based on latest clarifications (via comments and edits), here some important points:

- The Maven `deploy` [phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) is meant for

  > done in the build environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.
- Hence, in your case you don't need to use the `deploy` phase nor the `maven-deploy-plugin`.
- Since Tomcat is the target server, you then need to use the [`tomcat7-maven-plugin`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/)

Here are few instructions:

**Configure your `pom.xml`**
Add to your `pom.xml` the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>tomcat8</server>
        <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Configure your `settings.xml`**
Add to your Maven `settings.xml` the following in the `servers` section:

```
<server>
    <username>maven</username>
    <password>maven</password>
    <id>tomcat8</id>
</server>
```

Note the matching `tomcat8` id between the settings and the plugin `configuration` above, `server` element.

**Configure Tomcat for deploy**
In the tomcat `conf` folder, configure the `tomcat-users.xml` file:

```
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="maven" password="maven" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

note the credentials matching with what we actually specified in the Maven settings.

**Try it**
Then from the command line you can finally invoke:

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

If you don't want to configure `settings.xml` nor `pom.xml`, you then need to pass several parameters via command line as following:

```
mvn org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy \ 
      -Durl=http://localhost:8080/manager/text \
      -Dusername=maven -Dpassword=maven
```

Note: `\` and newlines added for readibility

Check full list of options on the official documentation of its [`deploy`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) goal.

Comment: Thanks @A_Di-Matteo , but I don't want to deploy to any remote servers, instead I want to deploy to my local tomcat instance.

Comment: @KuraiBankusu then you should have specified it :) the `deploy` phase by default is not meant for that, you hence need to use the `tomcat7-maven-plugin`, not the `maven-deploy-plugin`

Comment: @KuraiBankusu check my update, it is more than enough I would say to get more understanding and first aid on the topic. Hope it helps

Comment: is it possible for Tomcat 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

@A_Di-Matteo's answer is correct for deploying to tomcat. But if you came here looking for how to deploy to a Maven repo without putting repo URLs in pom.xml then here's your answer:

```
mvn deploy -DskipTests -DaltDeploymentRepository=myrepoid::default::https://maven.example.org/repository/maven-releases
```

Instead of `altDeploymentRepository`, you could also use `altReleaseDeploymentRepository` or `altSnapshotDeploymentRepository`

More details in docs: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html